# SP-2016 & WS-Federation : Missing WCT time parameter

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I'm in the process of setting up WS-Federation on an on-prem SP-2016 installation and the Identity Provider server is stating that SP-2016 is not sending a WCT "time" parameter. I've confirmed this with  Fiddler captures -- the parameters *wa*, *wctx*, and *wtrealm* are present, but not *wct*.

The OASIS standard states that this WCT parameter is optional but does anyone know how to configure SP-2016 so that it includes the WCT parameter when it redirects the user to the Identity Provider for authentication?

Thanks!